# Is my algerbra correct for my work dealing with the alternating series test for: $a_n = {(-4)^n \over n4^n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have two questions (see "**(1)**/**(2)** **Is this valid**" sections) below.

Given the series: $a_n = {(-4)^n \over n4^n} $

I'd like to see if this converges and think this is an alternating harmonic series.

The terms are : $ -1 + {1\over2} - {1\over3} + {1\over4} - \space... \space+ {(-4)^n \over n4^n}$

So what is $b_n$?

**(1) Is this valid?** $a_n = (-1)^n \cdot {4^n\over n4^n}$. If so then $b_n = {4^n\over n4^n}$.

Assuming my algebra is valid then I can compute the limit of $b_n$ as $n \to \infty$. When I do this I end up with $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {1\over n} = 0$ as expected.

---

My textbook also mentioned I can get $b_n$ like follows:

$$b_n = \left|{(-4)^n \over n4^n}\right|$$

Using this approach, how do I handle the absolute values?

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left|{(-4)^n \over n4^n}\right|$

**(2) Is it valid** to write:

$$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {\left|(-4)^n\right| \over \left|n4^n\right|}$$
$$\require{cancel} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {\cancel{\left|(-4)^n\right|} \over \left|n\cancel{4^n}\right|}$$
$$ = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {1\over |n|} = 0$$

Comment: Yes, they are just basic exponent laws. In (2), the absolute value cancels out the $-1^n.$

Comment: The value of the alternating sum is $-ln(2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n4^n}{n4^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\\b_n=|a_n|=|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}| =\frac{|(-1)^n|}{|n|}=\frac{1}{|n|}$$